# How to validate fields and get validated output

Tags: python

I'm trying to validate the values in the model and get as output the validated values. The only example in the documentation is the following code, which doesn't show how exactly this is done so I can't extend on it.

```
>>> from schematics.models import Model
>>> from schematics.types import StringType, BooleanType
>>> from schematics.exceptions import ValidationError
>>>
>>> class Signup(Model):
...     name = StringType()
...     call_me = BooleanType(default=False)
...     def validate_call_me(self, data, value):
...         if data['name'] == u'Brad' and data['call_me'] is True:
...             raise ValidationError(u'He prefers email.')
...         return value
...
>>> Signup({'name': u'Brad'}).validate()
>>> Signup({'name': u'Brad', 'call_me': True}).validate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ModelValidationError: {'call_me': [u'He prefers email.']}
```

I made a version of it but removed `data` and `value` from arguments. `Client` is the name of my model. So when I do the following I get the desired result as output:

```
client.validate_client(client.to_native())
```

However,

- first of all, this doesn't seem a clean way. `client` already has all the values and so I wouldn't need to do this.
- Also, I like to get this to update the values of client as an outcome of validation.

For the first part, I did something line this:

```
def validate_client(self):
    data = self.to_native()

    ...

    return data
```

But I don't think this is the best way to do this and I am not sure about the second issue of updating the values. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

This is the code I have and I want the client value for employer to be set to `'unspecified'` and client `full_name` to be set as specified in the function.

```
class LowerCaseEmailType(EmailType):

    def convert(self, value, context=None):
        value = super(LowerCaseEmailType, self).convert(value, context)
        return value.lower()


class CleanedStringType(StringType):
    converters = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This takes in all the inputs as String Type, but takes in an extra
        input called converters.
        Converters must be a list of functions, and each of those functions
        must take in exactly 1 value , and return the transformed input
        """
        if 'converters' in kwargs:
            self.converters = kwargs['converters']
        del kwargs['converters']
        super(CleanedStringType, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def convert(self, value, context=None):
        value = super(CleanedStringType, self).convert(value, context)
        for func in self.converters:
            value = func(value)
        return value  # will have a value after going through all the conversions in order


class Client(Model):
    """
    Client Model
    """
    first_name = CleanedStringType(required=False,
                                   converters=[lambda x: re.sub(r"[!@#$%&\(\)\^]+", ' ', x),
                                               lambda x: x.strip()])
    last_name = CleanedStringType(required=False,
                                  converters=[lambda x: re.sub(r"[!@#$%&\(\)\^]+", ' ', x),
                                              lambda x: x.strip()])
    full_name = CleanedStringType(required=False,  
                                  converters=[lambda x: re.sub(r"[!@#$%&\(\)\^]+", ' ', x),
                                              lambda x: x.strip()])
    employer = StringType(required=False)
    created = StringType(default=" ")    
    updated = StringType(default=" ")     
    email = LowerCaseEmailType(required=False)

    def validate_client(self):
        data = self.to_native()

        if data.get('first_name') and data.get('last_name'):
            data['full_name'] = ' '.join([data['first_name'], data['last_name']])

        if data.get('full_name') is None:
            if data.get('first_name') is None:
                error_message = 'first name missing'
            else:
                error_message = 'last name missing'
            logger.error('info: {} for {}'.format(error_message, data))
            raise ValidationError(error_message)

        if data.get('employer') is None:
            logger.warning('info: employer missing for {}'.format(data))
            data['employer'] = 'unspecified'

        return data
```

Comment: I guess you are using the [schematics](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) python library? There is a [chapter on validation](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/validation.html) how exactly does the validation you want to do differ from the validation done by the library? It seems like `validate_[ATTRIBUTE_NAME]` is automatically called when you execute `model.validate()` so I think you are not using the library as intended as far as I understood from your question.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if you really mean "validation". As far as I understand validation, validation checks if an object conforms to a specification. The output of validation is never "updated data" but always just "conforms to the specificion or not" (possibly with how exactly it does not conform, but never automatically made conform).

Comment: @syntonym you're right about using schematics library. When I do `model.validate()` it seems not to do anything but `model.validate_client(model.to_native())` seems to be doing what I am looking for. But you might be right in "validation" might not be exactly what I am looking for. But from examples in the documentation it seems it's capable of doing what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you add example model definition and output of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @syntonym I added more code to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`pre_setattr`](https://github.com/schematics/schematics/blob/master/schematics/types/base.py#L279). It is called with the value when you set a value of a model ([code](https://github.com/schematics/schematics/blob/master/schematics/models.py#L55) in question).

For the eymployer I think you want to set a default. To me this seems to behave exactly as you want.

I think `fullname` should not be on the model, because you can have inconsistent data where `firstname + lastname != fullname`. If you need it later you could implement that via [`@serialized`](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/exporting.html#serializable).